# Why do $2\log x$ and $\log x^2$ look different when graphing?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I understand how both graphs are drawn, but I do not understand why you cannot just convert one into another. It feels natural to me to just convert $2\log x$ to $\log x^2$ and not have to worry about the domain restriction.

Comment: How did you graph them? I suspect that $\log(x^2)$ graphs with $x<0$ as well, but for $x>0$ they graph the same.

Comment: $\log x^2 = 2 \log |x| \ne 2 \log x\,$. `It feels natural to ... not have to worry about the domain restriction` Natural or not, that's the wrong approach here and in general.

Comment: Yes, @ThomasAndrews, that's what confused me - the domains

Comment: Basically, $\log -1$ is not defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wonderful thing about math is that you don't have to rely on your feelings to get the right answer.

You have two functions
$$
f(x) = 2\log(x) \\
g(x) = \log(x^2)
$$
Indeed for $x > 0$ you have $f(x) = g(x)$. Both functions aren't defined for $x=0$. The domain of $f$ is all positive real numbers, but the domain of $g$ also contain the negative numbers. So the two functions aren't equal.

It is possible that you entered the functions wrong on your calculator. You might have entered $\log(x^2)$ as $(\log(x))^2$ and in this case you  obviously get something different. So make sure you have the right parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}lf: &\mathbb{R}^*_+&\to \mathbb{R}\\&x&\to 2\log x\end{array} \quad \implies2\log x=\log x^2$

---

$\begin{array}lg: &\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}&\to \mathbb{R}\\&x&\to \log x^2\end{array} \quad \implies\log x^2=2\log |x|$